# Trouble proving identity with Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, legendre-polynomials

I am trying to prove the following identity:

$$\int_0^\pi P_l(\cos\theta)P_{l'}(\cos\theta)\sin\theta d\theta = \biggl\lbrace \begin{matrix}0, \ if \ l' \neq l \\ \frac2{(2l+1)}, \ if \ l'=l \end{matrix} \tag{1}$$

Where $P_l$ and $P_l'$ are defined by Rodrigues' formula

$$P_l(x) = \frac1{2^l l!} \ \partial_x^l(x^2 - 1)^l \tag{2}$$
$$P_{l'}(x) = \frac1{2^{l'} {l'}!} \ \partial_x^{l'}(x^2 - 1)^{l'} \tag{3}$$

I substituted $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ in order to evaluate the integral for $l \neq l'$, but I am having difficulty tackling the $\partial_{\cos \theta}^l (\cos^2\theta-1)^l$ portion for both $l$ and $l'$

I tried to do the first 5 differentiations from $\partial^l$ to $\partial^{l-5}$ to find some sort of pattern but am unable to find anything useful.

Any hints or reference would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no need to  keep complicated trigonometric functions.  Instead, change the variable in the integral $\cos \theta = x$.

$$\int_0^\pi P_l(\cos\theta)P_{l'}(\cos\theta)\sin\theta d\theta =\int_{-1}^1P_l(x)P_{l^\prime}(x)dx$$

Now you can  use Rodrigues'  formula in the integral to show  the  orthogonality.
For instance, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328034/showing-orthogonality-of-legendre-polynomials-using-rodrigues-formula).

Comment: very nice my friend