# Orthogonality Legendre Polynomial WITHOUT integration by parts

Tags: real-analysis, legendre-polynomials

I'm aware of the two questions [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737301/associated-legendre-polynomials-orthogonality-proof-int-11-p-kmx-cdot)] and [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328034/showing-orthogonality-of-legendre-polynomials-using-rodrigues-formula)] but I'm trying to proof the orthongonality of the Legendre polynomials *without integration by parts*.
$$
\int_{-1}^1 P_\ell(x)P_{\ell'}(x) dx = \frac{2}{2\ell+1}\delta_{\ell \ell'}
$$
defined by the **Rodrigues Formula**
$$ P_\ell(x) =  \frac{1}{2^\ell \ell!} \left(\frac{d}{dx} \right)^\ell (x^2-1)^\ell$$

I want to know how can I continue if I start as follows
$$
P_l(x) =  \frac{1}{2^\ell \ell!} \left(\frac{d}{dx} \right)^\ell \sum_{k=0}^\ell \binom{\ell}{k}(-1)^{\ell-k}x^{2k} \\
=  \frac{1}{2^\ell \ell!}  \sum_{k=0}^\ell \binom{\ell}{k}(-1)^{\ell-k}\binom{2k}{\ell}\ell!\ x^{2k - \ell}
$$
The last integral can be summed  starting from $k \geq \ell/2$ instead of zero. Now substitute the in the integral the suitable expressions
$$
\frac{1}{2^{\ell+\ell'} \ell! \ell'!}\int_{-1}^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^\ell \binom{\ell}{k}(-1)^{\ell-k}\binom{2k}{\ell}\ell!\ x^{2k - \ell}\right)\left(\sum_{k'=0}^{\ell'} \binom{\ell'}{k'}(-1)^{\ell'-k'}\binom{2k'}{\ell'}\ell'!\ x^{2k' - \ell'}\right) dx \\
=\frac{1}{2^{\ell+\ell'} \ell! \ell'!}\int_{-1}^1  \left( \sum_{k,k'=0}^{\ell,\ell'} (-1)^{\ell + \ell'-(k+k')} \binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell'}{k'}\binom{2k}{\ell}\binom{2k'}{\ell'}\ell!\ell'!\ x^{2(k+k') - (\ell+\ell')}\right) dx \\
=\frac{1}{2^{\ell+\ell'} \ell! \ell'!}\left[ \sum_{k,k'=0}^{\ell,\ell'} (-1)^{\ell + \ell'-(k+k')} \binom{\ell}{k}\binom{\ell'}{k'}\binom{2k}{\ell}\binom{2k'}{\ell'}\ell!\ell'!\ \frac{x^{2(k+k') - (\ell+\ell')+1}}{2(k+k') - (\ell+\ell')+1} \right]_{-1}^1 \\
$$
In the sum above only non-negative powers of $x$ count, since $\ell$-th and $\ell'$-th derivatives were taken. Now if $\ell + \ell'$ is odd, then the integral vanishes, since the powers of $x$ are even. But if $\ell + \ell'$ is even then it is not clear ... I don't know yet how to conclude the rest.

Comment: For $\ell+\ell'$ even, it seems, by trial, that the quantity in brackets vanish both in $1$ and in $-1.$

Comment: @enzotib if I understand correctly, you mean the sum in brackets is zero for $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ *separately*

Comment: Yes, I am saying exactly this

Comment: I should have added that since I took the $\ell$-th derivatives, only non-negative powers must be considered

Comment: This is somehow evident from binomial coefficients. Can be included in formulae by writing $$\sum_{k=\lfloor(l+1)/2\rfloor}^l$$